# Migrating data to new mysql rds instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

I have 1TB size mysql database for production . Now i want to migrate this database on new mysql RDS instance .
Please suggest me which backup policy should i apply here like Mysqldump,XtraBackup . ?

Comment: Depends on database complexity. Maybe simple structure backup + `SELECT INTO OUTFILE`/`LOAD DATA INFILE` will be the best solution.

Comment: Can we restore Xtrabackup backup of Mysql to newly launched rds mysql instance ?

Comment: Please consult with your RDS support.

Comment: https://aws.amazon.com/dms/ is also an option worth checking, if you'd like to bypass most of the manual setup and maintenance.